# How to generate automatic url which is given permission for 3 times in PHP?

Tags: php, url, permissions

I would like to generate a URL which will have a unique code tail at the and only will be used 3 times. After accessing 3 times from the link. the url will expire. How can I do this?
Basically I think I need to create a database and map the permission for the url and have acountdown number? is there any better way of doing this? An example of this is in facebook you can just copy and send a link  to the people to see your pictures without going online or being your friends. ?

Comment: `Basically I think I need to create a database and map the permission for the url and have acountdown number?` Without `I think` and the question mark you've got yourself the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already thought of your own solution! There is no easier way.

Lets have a look at what you need:

1. An url referring to a specific page (or an image in your case)
2. A limit of times your url can be visited
3. A count of the amount of visits

All 3 requirements seem to need a database. You can use an alternative database, such as local xml files but that would be way more work than using a mysql database for instance.

Comment: Thank you. So another thing gives me headache because I am not familiar with php. for example: http://localhost/MyApp/mypage.php?number=1234567899 this is lets say the url.Basically this is to send a query  to database and show the page. What I would like to do is instead of having that url. I would like to be able to just type hhtp://localhost/MyApp/123456789 and get the same result. I have heard about url rewriting but I dont really know how to use it. Can you give an  example and show that if its easier for you. Thank you.

Comment: This might be surprising you, but URL rewriting hasn't to do with PHP. This is where a .htaccess file comes around the corner. I just reposted a blogpost of mine which has an example of a .htaccess file and how to get it using PHP [here](http://www.timseverien.nl/blog/perfect-htaccess). Frankly, it's too much to explain in this comment but in that article you see that 1 line of PHP code. Just save the file as .htaccess in your root folder. The array it returns will have the values that are in your url, which in this case would be the image ID. If you cant fix it please open a new question...

Comment: since it's completely irrelevant to this question. Also, if someone answers your question people are very pleased if that is voted the correct answer to the question. Again, if you need more help with the url rewriting, open a new question and I'm willing to write it all out for you!